# Erro de injeção no recurso Bean

Tags: jsf, github, spring-security

Então pessoal, estou desenvolvendo em jsf e me deparei com esse erro aí, alguém tem alguma idéia do que possa ser??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado telaAlunosBean
br.edu.ifba.as.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:39)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado telaAlunosBean
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
br.edu.ifba.as.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:26)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

root cause

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado telaAlunosBean
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:94)
org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:58)
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeToolbarGroups(ToolbarRenderer.java:76)
org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeEnd(ToolbarRenderer.java:44)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(OutputPanelRenderer.java:65)
org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:41)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
br.edu.ifba.as.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:26)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

root cause

com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:94)
org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:58)
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeToolbarGroups(ToolbarRenderer.java:76)
org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeEnd(ToolbarRenderer.java:44)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(OutputPanelRenderer.java:65)
org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:41)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
br.edu.ifba.as.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:26)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:94)
org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:58)
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeToolbarGroups(ToolbarRenderer.java:76)
org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeEnd(ToolbarRenderer.java:44)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(OutputPanelRenderer.java:65)
org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:41)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
br.edu.ifba.as.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:26)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
...estorou o limite de caracteres
```

Comment: Coloca o código da página jsf e do MBean.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra coloquei, dá uma olhada por favor

Answer (score 0):

Managed Bean de TelaAlunosBean

```
package br.ifba.edu.as.bean;

import br.edu.ifba.as.entidades.formulario.Aluno;
import br.edu.ifba.as.entidades.formulario.Turma;
import br.edu.ifba.as.entidades.usuario.Usuario;
import br.edu.ifba.as.logica.telaAluno.AlunoTabela;
import br.edu.ifba.as.rn.AlunoRN;
import br.edu.ifba.as.rn.TurmaRN;
import br.edu.ifba.as.rn.UsuarioRN;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "telaAlunosBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TelaAlunosBean implements Serializable{
private Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
private Aluno novoAluno = new Aluno();
private Turma turma = new Turma();
private Turma novaTurma = new Turma();


private String estadoTela = "listarFichas";
private String pesquisa = "";
private String filtroCurso = "todos";
private String filtroModalidade = "todos";

private List<Turma> turmas;

private List<Aluno> alunos;
private List<AlunoTabela> alunosTabela = new ArrayList<>();
private Set<String> modalidades;
private Set<String> cursos;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    TurmaRN turmaRN = new TurmaRN();
    listarFichas();
    turmas = turmaRN.listar();
}    

public void preCadastro(){
    System.out.println("PreCadastro");
    System.out.println("Alno.cpf: " + novoAluno.getCpf());
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    AlunoRN alunoRN = new AlunoRN();
    UsuarioRN usuarioRN = new UsuarioRN();

    usuario.setAtivo(Boolean.FALSE);
//        usuario.getPermissao().add("ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR");
    usuarioRN.salvar(usuario);
    System.out.println("Salvou usuario");
    novoAluno.setUsuario(usuario);
    alunoRN.salvar(novoAluno);
    System.out.println("Aluno pré-cadastrado");
// Mostrar mensagem        
    novoAluno = new Aluno();
}

public void cadastrarTurma(){
    TurmaRN turmaRN = new TurmaRN();
    turmaRN.salvar(novaTurma);
    System.out.println("Turma cadastrada"); 
    novaTurma = new Turma();
// Mostrar mensagem        
}

public void excluirTurma(Turma turma){
    TurmaRN turmaRN = new TurmaRN();
    if(turma != null) {
        turmaRN.excluir(turma);
    }
}

public void editarTurma(Turma turma) {
    TurmaRN turmaRN = new TurmaRN();

    if(turma != null) {
        turmaRN.salvar(turma);
    }
}

public void listarFichas(){
    AlunoRN alunoRN = new AlunoRN();
    TurmaRN turmaRN = new TurmaRN();
    modalidades = new HashSet<>(turmaRN.listarModalidades());
    cursos = new HashSet<>(turmaRN.listarCursos());
    alunosTabela = new ArrayList<>();
    alunos = new ArrayList<>();
    int i;


    if(filtroModalidade == null || "todos".equals(filtroModalidade)){
        if(filtroCurso == null || "todos".equals(filtroCurso)){
            alunos = alunoRN.listar();
            if(alunos != null || !alunos.isEmpty()){
                for(i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++){
                    AlunoTabela alunoTabela = new AlunoTabela(alunos.get(i));
                    alunosTabela.add(alunoTabela);
                }
            }
        }else{
            alunos = alunoRN.listarPorCurso(filtroCurso);
            if(alunos != null || !alunos.isEmpty()){
                for(i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++){
                    AlunoTabela alunoTabela = new AlunoTabela(alunos.get(i));
                    alunosTabela.add(alunoTabela);
                }
            }                
        }
    }else{
        if(filtroCurso == null || "todos".equals(filtroCurso)){
            alunos = alunoRN.listarPorModalidade(filtroModalidade);
            if(alunos != null || !alunos.isEmpty()){
                for(i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++){
                    AlunoTabela alunoTabela = new AlunoTabela(alunos.get(i));
                    alunosTabela.add(alunoTabela);
                }
            }
        }else{
            alunos = alunoRN.listarPorModalidadeCurso(filtroModalidade, filtroCurso);
            if(alunos != null || !alunos.isEmpty()){
                for(i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++){
                    AlunoTabela alunoTabela = new AlunoTabela(alunos.get(i));
                    alunosTabela.add(alunoTabela);
                }
            }
        }            
    }

    changeToListarFichas();
}

public void listarAlunosBolsa(){
    AlunoRN alunoRN = new AlunoRN();
    int i;
    alunosTabela = new ArrayList<>();
    alunos = alunoRN.listar();
    if(alunos != null || !alunos.isEmpty()){
        for(i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++){
            AlunoTabela alunoTabela = new AlunoTabela(alunos.get(i));
            alunosTabela.add(alunoTabela);
        }
    }        
    changeToListarPorBolsa();

}

public void buscar(){
    AlunoRN alunoRN = new AlunoRN();
    int i;
    alunosTabela = new ArrayList<>();
    alunos = alunoRN.buscarCPFNomeRG(pesquisa);
    if(alunos != null || !alunos.isEmpty()){
        for(i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++){
            AlunoTabela alunoTabela = new AlunoTabela(alunos.get(i));
            alunosTabela.add(alunoTabela);
        }
    }           
    pesquisa = "";
    changeToPesquisar();
}

// Controle de Tela
public boolean isPreCadastro(){
    return "preCadastro".equals(this.estadoTela);
}
public void changeToPreCadastro(){
    this.estadoTela = "preCadastro";
}

public boolean isListarFichas(){
    return "listarFichas".equals(this.estadoTela);
}
public void changeToListarFichas(){
    this.estadoTela = "listarFichas";
}

public boolean isListarPorBolsa(){
    return "listarPorBolsa".equals(this.estadoTela);
}
public void changeToListarPorBolsa(){
    this.estadoTela = "listarPorBolsa";
}

public boolean isPesquisar(){
    return "pesquisar".equals(this.estadoTela);
}
public void changeToPesquisar(){
    this.estadoTela = "pesquisar";
}


// Getters e Setters

public Aluno getAluno() {
    return aluno;
}

public void setAluno(Aluno aluno) {
    this.aluno = aluno;
}

public Aluno getNovoAluno() {
    return novoAluno;
}

public void setNovoAluno(Aluno novoAluno) {
    this.novoAluno = novoAluno;
}

public Turma getTurma() {
    return turma;
}

public void setTurma(Turma turma) {
    this.turma = turma;
}

public Turma getNovaTurma() {
    return novaTurma;
}

public void setNovaTurma(Turma novaTurma) {
    this.novaTurma = novaTurma;
}

public String getEstadoTela() {
    return estadoTela;
}

public void setEstadoTela(String estadoTela) {
    this.estadoTela = estadoTela;
}

public String getPesquisa() {
    return pesquisa;
}

public void setPesquisa(String pesquisa) {
    this.pesquisa = pesquisa;
}

public String getFiltroCurso() {
    return filtroCurso;
}

public void setFiltroCurso(String filtroCurso) {
    this.filtroCurso = filtroCurso;
}

public String getFiltroModalidade() {
    return filtroModalidade;
}

public void setFiltroModalidade(String filtroModalidade) {
    this.filtroModalidade = filtroModalidade;
}

public List<Turma> getTurmas() {
    return turmas;
}

public void setTurmas(List<Turma> turmas) {
    this.turmas = turmas;
}

public List<Aluno> getAlunos() {
    return alunos;
}

public void setAlunos(List<Aluno> alunos) {
    this.alunos = alunos;
}

public List<AlunoTabela> getAlunosTabela() {
    return alunosTabela;
}

public void setAlunosTabela(List<AlunoTabela> alunosTabela) {
    this.alunosTabela = alunosTabela;
}

public Set<String> getModalidades() {
    return modalidades;
}

public void setModalidades(Set<String> modalidades) {
    this.modalidades = modalidades;
}

public Set<String> getCursos() {
    return cursos;
}

public void setCursos(Set<String> cursos) {
    this.cursos = cursos;
}



}
```

Página JSF Entrevistas

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<ui:composition>
<h:form>
        <p:outputPanel id="toolbar">
            <p:toolbar>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:inputText value="#{telaAlunosBean.pesquisa}" placeholder="Nome, CPF, RG"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" update="panel" action="#{telaEntrevistaBean.buscar()}"/>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbar>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                    <p:commandButton value="Entrevistas realizadas" update="panel" action="#{telaEntrevistaBean.changeToEntrevistasFeitas()}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Entrevistas a fazer" update="panel" action="#{telaEntrevistaBean.changeToEntrevistasNaoFeitas()}"/>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel id="panel">

            <p:panel header="Entrevistas Realizadas" rendered="#{telaEntrevistaBean.entrevistasFeitas}">
                <p:dataTable var="entrevistaFeita" value="#{telaEntrevistaBean.entrevistas}">
                    <p:column>

                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

            </p:panel>

            <p:panel header="Entrevistas Não realizadas" rendered="#{telaEntrevistaBean.entrevistasNaoFeitas}">

            </p:panel>

            <p:panel header="Resultados da busca" rendered="#{telaEntrevistaBean.pesquisar}">

            </p:panel>

        </p:outputPanel>

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Lembrando que isso também acontece com outras páginas JSF...

Comment: As páginas que não precisam autenticação, exemplo Index, são acessadas? Por que você  comentou essa linha: //usuario.getPermissao().add("ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR"); Ela não seria para da permissão para entrar na página? Ou você está dando permissão de outra forma?

Comment: Aquilo ali era só um teste pra criar um usuário adm, os usuários comuns são criados nas classes de regra de negócio... Enfim era só um problema com o null quando não tinha nenhum dado cadastrado no banco